# How to Mount a Drive with Right Filesystem?

Tags: linux, centos, mount, partition, hard-disk

I am trying to mount the device /dev/xvdc on my CentOS system.  When I run an fdisk command I get:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1   *           1          33      262144   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/xvda2                  33       13055   104594432   83  Linux 
Disk /dev/xvdc: 1073.7 GB, 1073741824000 bytes 255 heads, 63
sectors/track, 130541 cylinders Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 =
8225280 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
0x00000000
```

And when I run `mount -t ext2 /dev/xvdc /bkp` a, I get:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdc,
     missing codepage or helper program, or other error
     In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
     dmesg | tail  or so
```

I want `/dev/xvdc` to be mounted as 50% `/bkp`, 25% `/fsys`, and 25% `/home2` What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're new, `gparted` is probably your friend as it's quite user-friendly for both the above options.  Use it to create three partitions on `/dev/xvdc` of the required size for your partioning scheme.

Once installed, run it as root:

```
gparted /dev/xvdc
```

Make sure you create the filesystems as well as the partitions.

Use `ext4` for the partition filesystems - `ext2` is old. Other filesystems are available (eg `xfs` or `btrfs`), but for now, stick to `ext4`.

---

As @terdon mentions, you may have to add the partitions/filesystems using the command line:

Note: the `#` are my comments - do not enter them.

```
fdisk /dev/xvdc
o # letter o for oscar to create a new partition table
n # to create a new partition
p # to make this new partition a primary one
1 # to number the partition (it will be /dev/xvdc1)
[Enter] # Press enter to accept the default start position of this new parition
+500G to make it approx 50% of the size of your 1TB disk
```

Repeat the above commands from the `o` for the second and third partitions, remembering to use `2` and `3` for the parition numbers and +250G for partition 3 size and leaving it as the default on the third partition (which will use the rest of the disk space).

You now have three empty partitions.  Use:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdc1
mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdc2
mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdc3
```

---

Once your partitions are created, you can mount them.

Your `mount` syntax above is incorrect. You need to tell the `mount` command which partition you want mounted (you've told it to use the whole disk):

```
mount -t ext2 /dev/xvdc1 /bkp
```

That will only work, if the partition on `/dev/xvdc1` is an `ext2` partition as you've used the `-t ext2` option.  It's best to leave this option out and allow `mount` to autodetect the filesystem type:

```
mount /dev/xvdc1 /bkp
```

and so on...

Comment: I don't think I have any xvdc partitions, where do you see those?  Not sure how to partition xvdc?

Comment: You're completely right - I miss read it even after editing your question! I'll edit the answer for you...

Comment: @Chris I deleted my answer now that gareth edited his so I'm answering your comment here. Yes, `gparted` is just a piece of software like any other. You can install it wherever you like. If you don't have a GUI, you can use `fdisk` instead.

Comment: @garethTheRed - Same result.  Shows the three partitions xvdc1,xdvc2,xdvc3 but when mounting get the same error. 

`Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvdc1               1       38246   307210963+  83  Linux
/dev/xvdc2           38247       82866   358410150   83  Linux
/dev/xvdc3           82867      130541   382949437+  83  Linux`
`mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdc1 /bkp`
`mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog`

Comment: Did you create a filesystem on each partition? If you didn't do so in `gparted` then `mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdc1` and so on...

Comment: @garethTheRed - I used fdisk and I did forget this step which solved the problem.  Thanks for the help and patience.