# Unable to mount new created partition on virtual machine running CentOS

Tags: mount, partition

I have `CentOS 6.6` (32-bit) running in `VMware Workstation 10.0.3 build-1895310`. I have just modified the Virtual Machine Settings, expanding the Hard Disk from *20 GB* to *30 GB*. I also created a new partition of type primary, `sda4`, with default start and stop cylinder number.

**fdisk /dev/sda** returns this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3916 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0000fba6

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64        2611    20458496   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda4            2611        3916    10483750   83  Linux
```

When I try to mount it, using **mount -t ext4 /dev/sda4 /data**, the following error is shown:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda4,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

To get the filesystem type, I typed the command **df -T**, and had the output below:

```
Filesystem           Type  1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_box0-lv_root
                     ext4   17971068 4039580  13011936  24% /
tmpfs                tmpfs    514720     228    514492   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1            ext4     487652   66444    395608  15% /boot
```

Comment: here [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155862/how-to-mount-a-drive-with-right-filesystem) a similar problem is formulated, but the answer provided needed gparted installed. since I failed to install gparted, I could not apply the solution presented there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a filesystem on the new partition still.  You created the partition, but it doesn't have a filesystem on it (as shown by its lack of entry in `df -T`).

Do `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda4` then try to mount it after